# samba setting on macosx

Tags: macos, samba, file-sharing, fileshare

when using linux, add  **guest ok = yes** in **smb.conf**

then PC could access \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with no name and password

with macosx i use file sharing with smb, could anyone tell me how to do it with GUI setting

thanks in advance

[image: everyone? guest?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GUI I don't think it's possible.

But you can try to modify the smb.conf file directly :
sudo vi /private/etc/smb.conf